# Using nested pseudo css selectors with react-emotion

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Running on a strange problem.

Following are two blocks of code. One of them works well and another just don't.

**This work**

```
const StyledButton = styled('button')`
  // Some styles here

  :first-child {
    // Some other styles
  }

  :first-child:after {
    content: 'F';
  }
`
// After get applied succesfully to the first child
```

**This doesn't**

```
const StyledButton = styled('button')`
  // Some styles here

  :first-child {
    // some other styles

    :after {
      content: 'F';
    }
  }
`
// After get applied to all nth child.
```

I'm using `react-emotion`.

Is this behavior intended or am I missing something? I want to achieve that `:after` should get applied to first-child only by using a similar approach to the second one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think there's an error in the code on the nested `:after`

The change that would, if I'm correct, solve your issue it to change the nested `:after` to `&:after` like so:

```
const StyledButton = styled('button')`
    // Some styles here

    &:first-child {//<====== note the & here
        // some other styles

        &:after { //<====== note the & here
           content: 'F';
        }
    }
}
```

The `&` is a placeholder for the parent selector, thus the code above will compile to:

```
button:first-child {
    // some other styles
}
button:first-child:after {
      content: 'F';
}
```

EDIT: [Sandbox with working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/9j6j292n0o)

Hope this helps!

`

Comment: I tried that as well. Just now figured out that if I put pseudo selector immediate after opening :first-child{} and add other styles after applying :after, it works. For example, 
:first-child{
  :after{}
  //other styles
} works.

Comment: @SanjayJoshi Take a look at this sandbox: `https://codesandbox.io/s/9j6j292n0o` (couldn't get the inline link to work on SO) , I've worked out the code into a small example